# Difference between くらい and くらいに

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-くらい

> ...., これ以上ないくらい**に**大きく目を見開いて、...　
>   she opened her eyes as wide as possible ...

I don't understand what に is doing here. I've seen plenty of examples where くらい acts adverbially without needing に. So why is it there, and what happens if I omit it?

If it helps, my literal understanding is to parse it as "to the extent that there is nothing more than this she widley opened her eyes".

I read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35910/is-the-word-%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84-a-noun-why-do-we-need-%E3%81%AE-between-%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84-and-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A) for particle の but that doesn't seem to apply here since に cannot (as far as I know) attach to ない.

Aside: does 目を見開く have some cultural significance e.g. does it represent concentration for example? The subject is currently beating a dog with a broom. It says that she made a 一 shape with her lips (seems like something you'd do if you were concentrating) and then the above sentence. I would normally associate wide eyes with fear (I don't think she's scared), but that would be passive. This sentence is active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ～くらい and ～くらいに can function adverbially, and I don't see a difference in meaning between:

> これ以上ない**くらいに**大きく目を見開いて・・・

and

> これ以上ない**くらい**大きく目を見開いて・・・

Similar examples:

> - 子供の**ときに**京都に引っ越しました。/ 子供の**とき**京都に引っ越しました。
> - 子供の**ころに**よく遊んだ公園 / 子供の**ころ**よく遊んだ公園
> - **すぐに**伺います。 / **すぐ**伺います。
> - **まっすぐに**立ってください。 / **まっすぐ**立ってください。
> - **しっかりと**持つ / **しっかり**持つ
> - **ぼんやりと**眺める / **ぼんやり**眺める

---

> does 目を見開く have some cultural significance e.g. does it represent concentration for example?

目を見開く *can* indicate concentration, but here in your example I think it shows 緊張 (tenseness) and/or 興奮 (agitation/excitement?) It can also be used to describe one's surprise, anger, fear, admiration, seriousness, etc.

---

(By the way, 目を[見張]{みは}る typically represents surprise and/or admiration.)

Answer (score 1):

Japanese dictionary "goo" shows the meaning of "位（くらい）" as 3 patterns.

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/63287/meaning/m0u/

I show you the usage of "に" for those model sentences. (explanations are ommited. See the original web site of the dictionary.)

１ 「一〇歳位の男の子」「その位で十分だ」

NG: 「一〇歳位に男の子」「その位に十分だ」

OK: 「今はもう、１０歳くらいに（は）なるだろう」、「いい加減にしろ。その位にしておけ」

OK: 「10歳くらいにはなる男の子」、「その位にはしても構わないだろう」

２ 「声も出ない位びっくりした」「犬位人間に忠実な動物はいない」「目に見えない位小さい」

OK: 「声も出ない位にびっくりした」「目に見えない位に小さい」

NG: 「犬位に人間に忠実な動物はいない」

OK:　「犬程に人間に忠実な動物はいない」＝「犬が示す程度に、人間に忠実な動物はいない」

３ 「簡単に否決される位なら、提案しなければよかった」

NG: 「簡単に否決される位になら、提案しなければよかった」

About the dictionary meaning 1st and 2nd, I can say that "位に" indicates the maximum value or degree that could be acceptable or realizable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning of your sentence don't change if you omit に.
I guess に is used to definition an adverbial function or just the emphasis.

I don't feel 目を見開く has some cultural significances. When man angry or when man are joyful, of course when man feel fear, in various situations, they open their eyes wide.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose they are same, because they can be replaced.
For example:

> - 同じくらい(に)
> - 小指くらい(に)

But くらいに is not very used. So I recommend to say くらい.